# Optimum number of folds in a $k$-fold cross-validation on a logistic regression

Tags: logistic, cross-validation, predictive-models

I want to perform a $k$-fold cross-validation on a logistic regression analysis.

I had initially considered the number of $k=10$ folds, as it is said to be somehow optimal.

However, I am not sure $10$ is the best in my case. Maybe something $k=5$ would make more sense.

This is my concrete situation:

- Total sample size $n=115$.
- Variable to predict: 35 NO vs 80 YES (target category).

So, in each of the $10$ folds, there would be just about 3 NO against 8 YES. Each fold acts as a validation set of the model built using the other $115-11=104$ cases as the training set. A validation set with just $11$ cases seems a bit strange to me.

So, **what would be an appropriate value for $k$, in my case? In other words, what would be the minimum desirable value for the validation sample size, in a cross-validation strategy?**

Answer (score 2):

I guess 100 repeats of 10-fold cross-validation.  A single 10- or 5-fold validation is imprecise.  The bootstrap would be better.  Be sure to use a proper accuracy scoring rule.